# How to do pathfinding when a unit has inertia?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

I'm currently working for pathfinding for a game where units are moving, but they have inertia.  Most typical pathfinding algorithms (A*, Djikastra, etc.) are simply designed to minimize the length of the path.

However, these techniques do not apply, as far as I know, to instances where the unit has inertia.  If the unit has inertia, then there is a significant difference in the cost to leave a tile in a particular direction based on the direction you want to go.

For example, the cost of leaving a tile proceeding North is significantly higher if you entered the tile from the East than if you entered from the South.  (In the former example, you would have to slow down to halt you East-West velocity, while in the latter, you could go straight through.)

The fact that the system has inertia means that in order to make a turn, you may have to slow down well in advance of making the turn.  My best thought to date is that you calculate the additional time it would take to slow down, and then add it to the heuristic cost of moving.  However, this would seem to imply that you could never add a tile to the closed list, as entering from another direction could fundamentally change the cost of moving.

So, is there any way to deal with inertia in pathfinding?

Comment: Could you limit your search to only look in the direction of inertia? As your direction changes, you'd slowly turn around.

Comment: Not really.  There are a lot of cases when you have to turn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a graph whose vertices are various combinations of tile+inertia and then do a normal pathfinding algorithm in that graph.

Comment: There would be a major increase in space required for this approach, no?

Comment: wouldn't this require infinitely many vertices?  Or at least a few orders of magnitude more (if we wanted to round inertia to a few decimal places)?

Comment: This sounds good to me. The assumption  is that the 'inertia' is discrete, being the number of available directions, but that is how I read the question.

Comment: This would be a major increase in space.  But not as bad as it seems.  You could do a coarse approximation to get the basic path, then smooth it out to find a local optimum.